# Show plots side by side

Tags: python, plot

I have functions that produces plots,

And i used it three time with different values to give me three plots.

My question is that i want to put the plots side by side horizontally to be able to compare them.
As doing the following show every plot after the other vertically.

```
make_plot(twiss)
make_plot(twiss_error)
make_plot(twiss_corrected)
```

Comment: There is enough info to find on the web to help you solve this, e.g. with matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

Comment: @Stefan Doing it with matplotlib is clear for me, but as i used a function that give every plot at a time I am not sure how to rearrange the plots after being produced

Comment: You don't sort out the layout after the plotting. You provide your function with the axis object that the function uses to plot the current data into.

Comment: @Mr.T Not sure what do you meant by provide your function with the axis object that the function uses to plot the current data into

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3)` returns for `ax` an array of axis objects. Each axis object can be used as a function parameter just like any other object (integer number, string, etc.) I assume you should get familiar with the [differences between pyplot and object oriented axis programming](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using matplotlib perhaps use subplots:

https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots (1,2)
```

[image]

you can access subplots by index as in

```py
 ax[0]
```

in your code.

Hope that this helps.